# Sprite sliding doors buttons, extra padding in firefox

Tags: css, sprite, css-sprites

I'm using the Sliding Doors technique with a sprite image to create span-able buttons, in Firefox, there's some extra padding on the right side, but everything looks perfect in IE and Chrome.

Here's the CSS and the image.. Any ideas?  Thank you!

```
.button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;  /* overrides extra padding in Firefox */
}


@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    /* Safari and Google Chrome only - fix margins */
    .button span {
        margin-top: -1px;
    }
}


.button { 
    position: relative;
    border: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 14px 0 0;
    background: transparent url(../img/button.png) no-repeat right -58px; 
}

.button span {
    padding: 5px 3px 8px 16px;
    background: transparent url(../img/button.png) no-repeat left top; 
    color:#6d6d6d;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    display: block; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center; 

}

.button:hover, .button.button_hover { 
    background-position: right -87px; 
}

.button:hover span, .button.button_hover span{
    background-position: 0 -29px;
}
```

!Sprite Image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv2Kz.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If FF4 add:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="file"] > input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;padding:0;margin:0;}
```

If older FF add:

```
::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;padding:0;margin:0;}
```

somewhere to the begining of your .css file. Firefox has it's own forms.css - you need to wipe out the user agent styles.